# Check if button's text is ellipsized

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I am running automated ui tests in xCode 7 in several languages (8).

It can happen that in longer worded languages texts don't fit, so the text gets ellipsized. Like

```
Availability
```

becomes

```
Av...ty
```

because it just doesn't fit in the box.

Can I somehow check by the test if text is ellipsized or not?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
CGSize size = [yourTitle sizeWithFont:yourFont];
if (size.width > button.titleLabel.bounds.size.width) {
   //has been ellipsized
}
```

Comment: This is production code which will not work in the test target.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode UI Testing should automatically handle this for you. Work with the text as if it wasn't ellipsized and you will be fine.

```
let label = XCUIApplication().staticTexts["Available"]
XCTAssert(label.exists)
```

See my [UI Testing Cheat Sheet on GitHub](https://github.com/joemasilotti/UI-Testing-Cheat-Sheet#testing-if-text-with-an-ellipse-exists) and my article, [UI Testing Cheat Sheet and Examples](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/) for more information.

Comment: Hi Joe, what I need is just the opposite. My test script can access the ellipsized element, that is no problem. What I need to do is to check IF the text is ellipsized.

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't think that's possible with UI Testing. The framework works through accessibility. And accessibility will always expose the full text without the ellipses.